# How can I optimize performance for QGIS 2.14 vector processing?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing

I am attempting to do a **Count points in polygon** routine for a clean looking 'density' grid.  I have around 800,000 points over a large polygon grid.

My workstation has 24 cores and 128gb RAM, and yet the process will often take twelve hours or longer to complete.  A look at the processor affinity shows 4 CPUs out of the bunch being hit at any one time for a moment, punctuated by extended periods where nothing appears to happen, and the output filesize does not increase.

My data are in the same SpatiaLite db, with indexes built.

The output does eventually complete, and gives me what I expect.  However, are there any tweaks or options I could explore in QGIS to improve this speed or distribute the processing across more CPUs?

Comment: Processing lacks parallel processing support so far. If your data is in SpatiaLite already, why not count in the DB?

Comment: If you'll start counting in SpatiaLite you must learn to do it right because spatial index is not utilized transparently but you must make a join or subquery.

Comment: @underdark, I wouldn't mind doing this, could you point me to a good tutorial or example?  Thanks!

Comment: Try http://northredoubt.com/n/2012/01/18/spatialite-and-spatial-indexes/

Comment: Thanks @underdark this looks helpful.  I'm currently running the sql statement in the DB Manager - it's not responding, but hopefully it'll finish (correctly) faster than the QGIS gui. :)  I'll report back when it's done.

Comment: @underdark, so I ran the SQL and it completed successfully - 30146740ms, or 502 minutes, or 8.4 hours.  This is not what I'd call "great" but it is around 4 to 5 hours faster than running the same thing in the QGIS gui.  I have further issues with DB Manager/QspatiaLite, but for SE compliance I'll initiate a new question for those.

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, how about writing it up as an answer so that other users who come to this question can find the answer easily?

Comment: There really is no solution.  I ran another case of the same thing and it ended up taking even longer than the GUI, and failed out.  Very few helpful examples out there.  I would rather see someone who is good at spatialite leave an authoritative answer.